# While loops using break and continue statements

Tags: python

I'm beginner. What is break and continue statement used for for a while statement?

```
while:
    break
    continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two key words can be used in a loop to change how it behaves. The break statement terminates the loop and moves on the next executable statement. The continue statement skips the rest of the code for the current pass of the loop and goes to the top to the test expression.

You may find this link helpful: [Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)

Example:

```
while True:
    if condition:
        break  # exits loop
    if condition:
        continue  # skips statements in ... and goes back to top
    ...
```

This loop would iterate until it reaches a break statement.

Answer (score 0):

**continue**
is used to skip a particular iteration of the loop

```
 while(i<5):
     if i == 3:
         continue
     print(i)
     i++
```

**break**
is used to get out of a loop

```
 while(i<5):
     if i == 3:
         break
     print(i)
     i++
```